# ValidationSummary not shown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created an asp.net mvc 3 razor view and added data annotation attributes on model properties. when i click the submit button on form, I see the validation messages as I used Html.ValidationMessageFor. but I dont see validation summary although I have added   @Html.ValidationSummary(true). Please suggestion fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing false:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```